# system.security.NoAccessException: Update access denied Even if there is no update

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am creating a visual force page of search object. Every thing runs ok, but when I try to log in as user who has permissions of update - read only, the following error is displayed :

> system.security.NoAccessException: Update access denied for
>   Technology__c

Here's my controller code that runs the search functionality:

```
 public List<Technology__c> searchResult   {get; set;}

     public void serach()
        {
          try
             {


              searchResult    = new List<Technology__c>();
              string searchlength = searchValue.replaceAll('[*]',''); 
              if(searchlength.length() < 2)
                 { 
                   message = TIMAS_Const.searchTerm;
                   visible = false;
                 }
              else
                 {
                 if(fullSearch)
                      {
                         searchResult  = null; 
                         visible = false;
                         fullSearch();
                         return;

                      }
                 visible = true;
                 string search_value = searchValue.replaceAll('[*]','%'); 
                 queryString = 'SELECT Id,isChecked__c ';
                 for(Schema.FieldSetMember fld : SObjectType.Technology__c.FieldSets.Technology_Search_Results.getFields() )
                        queryString += ', ' + fld.getFieldPath();
                 queryString += ' FROM Technology__c ';
                 queryString += ' WHERE  ( Name LIKE  \'%'+ search_value +'%\'' ;
                 queryString += ' OR Technology_Sinonym__c  LIKE  \'%'+ search_value +'%\'' ;
                 queryString += ' OR Innovators_Text__c  LIKE  \'%'+ search_value +'%\'' ;
                 queryString += ' OR Internal_Synonym__c like \'%' + search_value +'%\')';
                 if(selectEvalOnly == true)
                    queryString += ' AND (Evaluated_Technology__c = true) ';
                 queryString += ' ORDER BY  Name DESC';
                 searchResult =  Database.query(queryString);
                 sizeOfResult =  'Found ' + String.valueOf(searchResult.size())+' Results';
                 if(searchResult.size() < 1)
                     {
                       message = TIMAS_Const.NoMatches;
                       visible = false;
                     } 

                 }
             }
             catch(Exception e){ ApexPages.addMessages(e);  message = TIMAS_Const.NoMatches; visible = false;  }
          }
```

Comment: When you say "everything runs ok", are you referring to when you run it as an Admin who has "modify all data" permissions? I think the problem is one of permissions and isn't related to your code. Do you get this same error when using a profile that has read only permissions on `Technology__c`? Have you checked both OWD and FLP along with any sharing rules on the problematic profile for `Technology__c`?

Comment: First when i say every thing run OK that mean when i am running as admin ,the permissions for Technology__c is view only and read but  for edit & delete it false in this case when i gave permissions for edit = true it run OK but they doesn't want permissions for edit this object and i am wonder where i do update for this object

Comment: Someone has to be given edit permissions in order to perform updates to the records. Your can always give object permissions, but restrict editing to record that are owned or use some other sharing model. Management can also decide which fields they want to allow edit permissions on by role, record status or a variety of other criteria. Countless possibilities here.

Answer (score 1):

Brief clarification regarding permission:

**Create:** You can create record on the permitted object. Read permission is required here.

**Read:** You can see records of the permitted object. You can not edit, delete record. No other permission required.

**Delete:** You can delete a record on permitted object. Read and Edit permissions are required here.

**Edit:** You can edit record fields on permitted object. Read permission is required here.

So, if you want to update a record you have to give "Edit" permission because you are changing the value. "Read" will not allow to make changes on record. Technically `Read + Edit` is required to make changes.

Alternatively, you can update record by using triggers if you don't want to give edit permission. Triggers run in system mode. Or use schedule classes which is scheduled by admin profile. Or use "with sharing" clause in apex class. But be careful with this.

Comment: I think you meant "without sharing", right?